# Flutter list of stateBuilder issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, state

So I'm creating this app that has a list of posts which follows a similar kind of structure.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getPosts() <-Custom function that returns data from firestore
  builder:(context,snapshot){
     return ListView.builder(
            builder:(context,index){
            Post v=_dataToPost(snapshot.data()[index]) <- Custom function that transforms the data into a post
              bool userLike=v.like;
                 return StatefulBuilder(
                    builder(context,setSheet)=>
                         IconButton(
                         onPressed:(){
                         _likePost <-Custom function that updates firestore to like a post
                         setSheet({
                         userLike=!userLike
               })
               })
               )}
               )}
               )
```

First of all I've been told that this isn't how you properly use statefulbuilder but I don't want to call setState everytime someone likes/dislikes a post. But I still need the like icon to change as soon as my user presses it (simply waiting for the _likePost function to run takes too long).

I also have noticed that when I do in fact call setState (to get more posts or smt) the like button reverts back to its previous state (before someone pressed it) for a split second before catching up to the firestore data. This makes the button flicker for a split second.

Any ideas? anything is appreciated I've been scratching my head for days...

Comment: related to your second issue with the like button, you are probably making an unwanted network call. You should initialize your futures in the `initState` , this video explains it well :  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYN46233cws)

Comment: so I wanted to use initState but the issue is that I only have access to the variable inside the stateful builder so can you do initState inside the statefulbuilder?

Comment: Can you clean up your indenting?  Hard to read mis-indented code.

Comment: This expression: "future: getPosts()" should assign the future to a variable in an initState so it is done once.  Then the "future:" should reference that variable (containing a future).

Comment: The issue im having with putting the future in initState is that I do need to make some changes to the future (i.e. .limit(numDocs) ) which is not possible and I also noticed that when I call setState it still reverts back to previous state disregarding any changes made